# How to removed repeated element with same class in parent div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove repeated element of same class in parent div. I have used following code but it's remove all the element except first.

```
var found = {};
$('.product-bottom').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(found[$this.data('id')]){
         $this.remove();   
    }
    else{
         found[$this.data('id')] = true;   
    }
});
```

Following is my HTML..

```
<div class="product-bottom">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
     </div>

     <div class="product-bottom">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
     </div>

     <div class="product-bottom">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
     </div>
```

I want to remove repeated `custom_product` class element in each parent div `product-bottom`. So my output will be..

```
 <div class="product-bottom">
    <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
    <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
 </div>

 <div class="product-bottom">
    <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
    <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>       
 </div>

 <div class="product-bottom">
    <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
    <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: in the first place, `why do you have repeated content?` is the question. You are trying to solve an [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/) may be.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph, I could not repeated content , these content comes dynamic so i want to remove that repeated class in parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector that selects all elements at an *index* greater than the *index* within the matched set.

```
var el = $(this).find('.button.custom_product:gt(0)');
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.product-bottom').each(function(){
  var el = $(this).find('.button.custom_product:gt(0)');
  el.prev('div').remove();
  el.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title1 of 1</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">1 of 1</a>
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title2 of 1</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">2 of 1</a>
</div>

<div class="product-bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title1 of 2</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">1 of 2</a>
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title2 of 2</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">2 of 2</a>
</div>

<div class="product-bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title1 of 3</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">1 of 3</a>
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title2 of 3</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">2 of 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Check this code here just I emoved the second element with selector  I hope its help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-bottom .col-lg-12:nth-of-type(2)').remove(); $('.product-bottom a:nth-of-type(2)').remove();
});
  </script>
</head>
<div class="product-bottom">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title 1</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
     </div>

     <div class="product-bottom">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title 1</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
     </div>

     <div class="product-bottom">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title 1</span></div>
        <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1"></a>
     </div>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Yeah. It works fine for me. easy way to remove element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure remains the same, you can use the `:last-of-type` pseudo-class to remove the repeated content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.product-bottom div:last-of-type').remove();
  $('.product-bottom .custom_product:last-of-type').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">1 of 1</a>
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">2 of 1</a>
</div>

<div class="product-bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">1 of 2</a>
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">2 of 2</a>
</div>

<div class="product-bottom">
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">1 of 3</a>
  <div class="col-lg-12"><span>Title</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="button custom_product" data-quantity="1">2 of 3</a>
</div>
```